# Включение заголовков друг в друга

Tags: c++

Например есть такой заголовок и класс :

```
#ifdenf __MATRIX_H__
#define __MATRIX_H__

#include "vector.h"

namespace math 
{
class Matrix 
{
public:
    void setRows(const Vector& v, 
                 const Vector& v2,
                 const Vector& v3,
                 const Vector& v4);
     union
        {
            struct {
                float x1, y1, z1, w1;
                float x2, y2, z2, w2;
                float x3, y3, z3, w3;
                float x4, y4, z4, w4;
            };

            float data[4][4];
        };
};

inline void Matrix::setRows(const Vector& v, const Vector& v2, const Vector& v3, const Vector& v4)
    {
        data[0][0] = v.x;
        data[0][1] = v.y;
        data[0][2] = v.z;
        data[0][3] = v.w;

        data[1][0] = v2.x;
        data[1][1] = v2.y;
        data[1][2] = v2.z;
        data[1][3] = v2.w;

        data[2][0] = v3.x;
        data[2][1] = v3.y;
        data[2][2] = v3.z;
        data[2][3] = v3.w;

        data[3][0] = v4.x;
        data[3][1] = v4.y;
        data[3][2] = v4.z;
        data[3][3] = v4.w;
    }
}
#endif
```

и такой :

```
#ifndef __VECTOR_H__
#define __VECTOR_H__

#include "matrix.h"

namespace math
{
class Matrix;
class Vector 
{
public:
    Vector operator * (const Matrix& rMatrix);
};
inline Vector Vector::operator * (const Matrix& rMatrix) const
    {
        float x = this->x * rMatrix.data[0][0] + this->y * rMatrix.data[1][0] + 
            this->z * rMatrix.data[2][0] + this->w * rMatrix.data[3][0];

        float y = this->x * rMatrix.data[0][1] + this->y * rMatrix.data[1][1] + 
            this->z * rMatrix.data[2][1] + this->w * rMatrix.data[3][1];

        float z = this->x * rMatrix.data[0][2] + this->y * rMatrix.data[1][2] + 
            this->z * rMatrix.data[2][2] + this->w * rMatrix.data[3][2];

        float w = this->x * rMatrix.data[0][3] + this->y * rMatrix.data[1][3] + 
            this->z * rMatrix.data[2][3] + this->w * rMatrix.data[3][3];

        return Vector(x, y, x, w);
    }
}
#endif
```

Вот основные методы из классов которые создают проблему. 
Как откомпилировать такой код ? Или как можно решить эту проблему ? Struct forward decl тут не поможет как я понимаю.

Comment: Поможет, поскольку для ссылки достаточно `forward declaration.`

Comment: если бы я возвращал ссылку или указатель то тогда да, но я же обращаюсь к полям класса в методе.

Comment: Вообще-то, подобный код должен вызвать ошибку компиляции, поскольку приведет к бесконечному взаимному включению заголовков. А ответ на вопрос Котик уже дал.

Кстати, вызов метода я не вижу. Если даете код, то давайте полностью.

Comment: это суть, сейчас сам код кину

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте разделить интерфейс и имплементацию.

```
// matrix.h

// тут нужен include guard, конечно
class Vector;

class Matrix 
{
public:
    Vector& operator * (const Vector& rhs);
};

// matrix.cpp
#include "matrix.h"
#include "vector.h"

Vector& Matrix::operator* (const Vector& v)
{
    // ...
}
```

И аналогично для вектора.

---

А вообще пока я писал, [[@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) уже правильно ответил.

Comment: спасибо, попробую )

Comment: forward decl в таком случае не помогает.

Comment: @Дмитрий Арцукевич: почему не помогает? У меня компилируется.

Comment: @VlaD вот, подправил код с гуардами и struct forward decl. Получаю ошибки компиляции все равно -  error C2027: use of undefined type 'OGE::math::Matrix'
1>          d:\workspace\projects\illuminationengine\math\vector.h(14) : see declaration of 'OGE::math::Matrix'

Comment: @Дмитрий Арцукевич: строка

    inline Vector Vector::operator * (const Matrix& rMatrix) const

должна быть в .cpp!

Comment: а заинлайнить её никак ?

Comment: не-а, потому что тогда проблема с порядком включения :) вы же доступаетесь к данным, вам нужен настоящий `#include`.